# Algorithm To Check A HashSet for a gap or modify the checked value to fit into a gap

Tags: c#, algorithm, hash

I have a HashSet of year ranges (HashSet<Tuple<int,int>>) where I want to check if a particular Tuple already exists.  OR, if a particular Tuple can be "bumped" in one (or both directions) to fit into a gap.

I've written a unit test that demostrates how it should work.

The test sets up the HashSet and then calls a NotImplemented method and checks the results.

I can't think of an incredibly great way to implement the last invocation/examination of the test.  The first 4 invocations/examinations are pretty simple;  I can handle those.

How could this be implemented?

```
    [Fact]
    public void Handled2Test()
    {
        //setup data
        var alreadyHandled = new HashSet<Tuple<int, int>>();
        alreadyHandled.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(1993, 1993));
        alreadyHandled.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(1999, 2004));

        // check a simple range that has no overlap
        var notHandle = this.GetIfNotHandled(alreadyHandled, new Tuple<int, int>(1994, 1998));
        notHandle.Should().Be(new Tuple<int, int>(1994, 1998));

        // check a range that has been handled specifically
        var handled = this.GetIfNotHandled(alreadyHandled, new Tuple<int, int>(1999, 2004));
        handled.Should().BeNull();

        // check a range that has been handled by a larger range that extends around the queried range
        handled = this.GetIfNotHandled(alreadyHandled, new Tuple<int, int>(2001, 2002));
        handled.Should().BeNull();

        // THIS IS THE ONE I NEED HELP WITH
        // check a range that has a one year overlap on the min side
        notHandle = this.GetIfNotHandled(alreadyHandled, new Tuple<int, int>(1993, 1998));
        // returns a Tuple where 1993 has been "bumped" to 1994
        notHandle.Should().Be(new Tuple<int, int>(1994, 1998));

    }

    private Tuple<int, int> GetIfNotHandled(HashSet<Tuple<int, int>> alreadyHandled, Tuple<int, int> tuple)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do here. Given a tuple `<x,y>`, there are 9 possibilities that match your requirements: `<x-1,y-1>`, `<x-1,y>`, `<x-1,y+1>`,`<x,y-1>`,`<x,y>`,`<x,y+1>`,`<x+1,y-1>`,`<x+1,y>`,`<x+1,y+1>`. Which of those are you interested in identifying?

Comment: And isn't a set supposed to contain immutable elements?

Comment: Well, there's more than 9.  9 in the example, but there's no requirements that the set and the ranges are as small as in the example.  In other words, there could be an element of <0,1000000>.  I am interested in finding that (1993,1998) can be "not found" if you bump the 1993 to 1994.  Or that (1994,1999) can be "not found" if it is bumped to (1994,1998).  But the amount of "bumping" is unlimited until the min number meets the max number and max number meets the min number or it encounters another predefined range.

Comment: Then a dictionary probably isn't your best data structure. If you use a sorted list or balanced binary tree, you can search for the next larger or smaller item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following implementation may be close to what you need. I am not sure I fully understand your requirements (and I am not sure you sufficiently specified all corner cases). But if I plug this method into your unit test, it seems to succeed.

```
private Tuple<int, int> GetIfNotHandled(HashSet<Tuple<int, int>> existingItems, Tuple<int, int> range)
{
        //first check if we find a full overlap with an existing item
        var fullOverlap = existingItems.FirstOrDefault(t => (t.Item1 <= range.Item1)
                                                         && (t.Item2 >= range.Item2));
        if (fullOverlap != null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        //look for a partial overlap, or the closest item below our range
        var lowerItem = existingItems.FirstOrDefault(t => (t.Item1 <= range.Item1) 
                                                       && (t.Item2 >= range.Item1) 
                                                       && (t.Item2 < range.Item2));
        if (lowerItem == null)
        {
            lowerItem = existingItems.Where(t => t.Item2 < range.Item1)?.OrderBy(t => t.Item2).Last();
        }

        //look for a partial overlap, or the closest item above our range
        var upperItem = existingItems.FirstOrDefault(t => (t.Item1 <= range.Item2) 
                                                       && (t.Item2 >= range.Item2) 
                                                       && (t.Item1 > range.Item1));
        if (upperItem == null)
        {
            upperItem = existingItems.Where(t => t.Item1 > range.Item2)?.OrderBy(t => t.Item1).First();
        }
        return new Tuple<int, int>(lowerItem.Item2 + 1, upperItem.Item1 - 1);
}
```

Note that this implementation may be suboptimal in terms of performance, if you have large lists. It lacks error handling and may not be sufficiently robust if your tuples can be inconsistent (e.g. Item1 larger than Item2). But it might get you started on a full implementation.